# Disalow robots for different purpose with 1 Directive

Tags: robots.txt

Can I combine the 2 directive below into one as show under it and google or bing bot will still follow my robots?  I have recently seen bingbot not following the second directive and thinking if I combine the directive they might follow it.

Original

```
User-agent:*
Disallow: /folder1/
Disallow: /folder2/

User-agent: *
Disallow: /*.png
Disallow: /*.jpg
```

Wanted to change to this

```
User-agent:*
Disallow: /folder1/
Disallow: /folder2/
Disallow: /*.png
Disallow: /*.jpg
```

Comment: Have you tried switching the user-agent like /*.png before. the folder ones?

Comment: no but I rather they follow the folder than the image if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [may only have *one*](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) record with `User-agent: *`:

> If the value is '*', the record describes the default access policy for any robot that has not matched any of the other records. **It is not allowed to have multiple such records in the "/robots.txt" file.**

When having more than one of these records, bots (that are not matched by a more specific record) might only follow the first one in the file.

So you *have* to use this record:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /folder1/
Disallow: /folder2/
Disallow: /*.png
Disallow: /*.jpg
```

Note that the `*` in a `Disallow` value has no special meaning in the original robots.txt specification, but some consumers use it as a wildcard.